# gauss newton algorithm - what starting values

Tags: algorithms

I am trying to implement the [wikipedia example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Newton_algorithm#Example) of the Gauss-Newton algorithm. Although it does work as intended, when changing the starting values, it takes significantly more iterations to converge and does not always land on the same values.

**I am trying to understand how the example computes the initial starting values input to the algorithm.**

I would appreciate if you kept in mind in your answers that I am new to algorithms and without a strong background in maths.

Comment: If there are several solutions, you won't always land at the same one, see for example the [Newton fractal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_fractal). Also, you are only guaranteed to converge quickly under some conditions, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Newton_algorithm#Convergence_properties).

Comment: In general, it can be hard to come up with a good initial guess unless you use some algorithmic strategy like picking the best guess out of a set of $N$ random initial values. Using some strategy like this could give you a potentially good starting point, but there's still no guarantee that you'll end up at a globally optimal solution if your model is nonlinear in the parameters you are estimating.